Is there a difference between Thermal Paste and Heatsink Plaster?
Is Heatsink Plaster the same as Thermal Paste?
I went to my wonderful local technology supply store (Elliott Electronic Supply). Their staff informed me that everything was the same and that SFDER-922 was the exact product for me to utilize. However, I am somewhat skeptical and wanted to attempt to confirm.
Is Thermal Paste the same? Isn't plaster utilized for different applications?
The machine I am utilizing it with is somewhat difficult to take apart and requires Thermal Paste be re-added. As such I will likely have to remove and re-apply thermal paste in the future.
Thank you immensely for any help you may be able to provide.

Heatsink plaster is permanent and used in cases where there may not be a way to clamp the CPU/heatsink down. Thermal paste is used interchangeably with thermal compound these days. Technically paste suggests glue/permanence as well but the term is used to describe non-permanent compounds too. If you are going to need to remove and re-apply, do NOT use heatsink plaster. Use a thermal paste/compound.

I've never heard the term heatsink plaster before.
When in doubt though always refer to the datasheet. I've found one here - from the datasheet

Scope of application:
Has high strength,
Fast bonding effect,
Applicable to various components, LEDs and
heat sinks that need to be directly bonded
firmly)

Referring back to your question

The machine I am utilizing it with is somewhat difficult to take apart and requires Thermal Paste be re-added. As such I will likely have to remove and re-apply thermal paste in the future.

This isn't in any way thermal compound. Its thermally conductive glue.
Conventionally with PCs - you're going to use thermal pads or thermal compound, but unlike this product they do not rely on the thermal solution for mechanical strength. You'd have it screwed, bolted or plastic retainered in some way. This sticks things together.
